# Slack API - Add a user to a channel

Tags: slack-api

Hi I want to add a user to a channel and I am using this API https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.invite. It returns a response with error code 'not_in_channel'. Is this the correct API to use ? if it is the error code does not make sense, because I am trying to add him because he is not in channel. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might be using the `xoxb` bot token to make the call to `conversations.invite`.That won't work because that's your bot's token and the bot can't take action on a channel they are not a member of. To invite the bot you'll need to use an `xoxp` token belonging to the authenticated user and making sure that user is a member of that channel.